# Rails 4 : Active record collection looping or iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

In my rails customer controller there is an active record collection object:

**1. @pay_invoices = Invoice.where(customer_id: @pay_cus_id)**

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Invoice id: 37, customer_id: 53, paid_amount: 960, devicemodel_id: 2, transaction_id: "6drv3s", created_at: "2016-01-04 05:29:03", updated_at: "2016-01-25 12:16:14">, #<Invoice id: 70, customer_id: 53, paid_amount: 80, devicemodel_id: 2, transaction_id: "2mr93s", created_at: "2016-01-28 09:02:43", updated_at: "2016-01-28 09:02:43">]>
```

Also in my controller I am using the **transaction_id:** column value to find out the transaction details in the Braintree payment gateway using the following Braintree API call:

```
 @tid = @pay_invoices[0].transaction_id

 @transaction = Braintree::Transaction.find(@tid)
```

This works fine for me, but the transaction details of the first **transaction_id:** from the **@pay_invoices** collection only can be retrieved using this code, I want to iterate through the **@pay_invoices** collection and each time I want to store the braintree transaction details into another collection, so that only I can display the payment details fro each transaction in my view.

How to achieve it ?

Comment: Does Braintree's api have something to load multiple transactions at once?

Comment: upon each iteration over active collection each time the braitree api call will be made by passing the transaction_id: with it, it returns a collcetion from that I want to store the status of the transaction into somewhere, this process continue till the loop iterate over all active record collection and that many transaction status also to be stored.

Comment: What I mean is, does it have an equivalent to `ActiveRecord`'s `where` clause, where you can pass an array of transaction ids?  Something like `Braintree::Transaction.where(transaction_id: [1,2,3])`?

Comment: I dont know about using where clause in Braintree call :O

Answer (score 0):

```
transaction_ids = Invoice.where(customer_id: @pay_cus_id).pluck(:transaction_id)
@transactions = []
transaction_ids.each do |t_id|
  @transactions << Braintree::Transaction.find(t_id)
end
```

Though if there is a where equivalent you could simply do something like

```
transaction_ids = Invoice.where(customer_id: @pay_cus_id).pluck(:transaction_id)
@transactions = Braintree::Transaction.where(transaction_id: transaction_ids)
```

Comment: thanks buddy for you help, I will try it after some time, and let you know if it solved my problem or not :)